# Add read_timeout to Mage_Cache_Backend_Redis

Tags: full-page-cache, redis

Although not set by default, is it possible (or does it even make sense) to add a read_timeout value to the Mage_Cache_Backend_Redis section in full_page_cache?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can set the value to something like this

```
  <read_timeout>10</read_timeout>
```

Inchoo has a very good Blog Article about this

http://inchoo.net/magento/using-redis-cache-backend-and-session-storage-in-magento/

Code snippet:

```
  <backend_options>
    <server>127.0.0.1</server>              <!-- or absolute path to unix socket -->
    <port>6379</port>
    <persistent></persistent>               <!-- Specify a unique string like "cache-db0" to enable persistent connections. -->
    <database>0</database>
    <password></password>
    <force_standalone>0</force_standalone>  <!-- 0 for phpredis, 1 for standalone PHP -->
    <connect_retries>1</connect_retries>    <!-- Reduces errors due to random connection failures -->
    <read_timeout>10</read_timeout>         <!-- Set read timeout duration -->
    <automatic_cleaning_factor>0</automatic_cleaning_factor> <!-- Disabled by default -->
    <compress_data>1</compress_data>        <!-- 0-9 for compression level, recommended: 0 or 1 -->
    <compress_tags>1</compress_tags>        <!-- 0-9 for compression level, recommended: 0 or 1 -->
    <compress_threshold>20480</compress_threshold>  <!-- Strings below this size will not be compressed -->
    <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib> <!-- Supports gzip, lzf and snappy -->
  </backend_options>
```